# Mongoose Encryption encrypts both fields. What do I do?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs, mongoose-schema

```
const adminsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
});

const secret = "Thinkyoucancrackthisone";
adminsSchema.plugin(encrypt, {
    secret: secret,
    encryptedFields: ["password"]
});
const Admin = new mongoose.model("Admin", adminsSchema);
```

```
app.post("/register", function (req, res) {
    const user = new Admin({
        username: req.body.user,
        password: req.body.pass
    });
    user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send("Admin creds added successfully");
        }
    });
});
```

So instead of getting 5 fields Im getting 4 fields with no username field

I tried different for different typos, different methods like excludefromencryption but it didnot work. I even tried dropping the collection starting anew.

Comment: The plugin you're using is this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-encryption?

What is an example payload sent to the /register endpoint, and what is the resulting document inserted into the DB

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the mongoose-encryption library ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-encryption ), that might be the problem.
It's meant for encrypting entire documents as far as I'm aware.

Try using the mongoose-field-encryption library instead ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-field-encryption ), for encrypting specific fields.

Also: "Always store your keys and secrets outside of version control and separate from your database."

You probably already know this and has added the secret just for the example; but remember to not have the secret directly in the source code. Use something like an environment variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share a more detailed part of code.
Also,
the model. `Save()` method does not/no longer accepts callbacks. So go ahead with async await or promise handling.

```js
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({
    email: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  try {
    await newUser.save();
    res.render('secrets.ejs');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```